# How can I find a Douglas-Peucker algorithm for simplification?

Tags: algorithm, simplify

I want to understand simplification methods in GIS. I searched the Internet and found that the best simplification method is the [Douglas-Peucker algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm). I could not find any information about the algorithm and how the algorithm works. Is there a resource detailing the methodology behind the algorithm?

Comment: A brief but complete and accurate description appears at http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/11915. It contains links to references.

Answer (score 2):

I found a Wikipedia article entitled [Ramer-Peucker-Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) which looks like a good starting point because it describes some pseudocode as well as links to take you into its full complexity.